# Reading and Writing Using DMA Character Device Driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, dma

I am using this character device driver https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf to do DMA. In the documentation, the author says to access the driver you can open the device file like this

```
  if ((fd  = open("/dev/udmabuf0", O_RDWR)) != -1) {
        buf = mmap(NULL, buf_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        /* Do some read/write access to buf */
        close(fd);
    }
```

I have two questions. The first is the type of buf, which I am assuming is char* rather than char[N], but I just want to be sure.

The second question is how to actually perform the reading and writing. Could I write by simply changing the characters to which buf is pointing, assuming it is a pointer?

```
buf = mmap(NULL, buf_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);    
buf = "I am doing some writing to dma";
```

If that is the case, will buf continue to change as the memory buf is mapped to is changing?

```
buf = mmap(NULL, buf_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
printf(buf) //"abcd"
sleep(10);
printf(buf) //"efgh"
```

Comment: `buf` is a _pointer_, not an array type. The `mmap` returns you an _address_ to a buffer intended to be used for I/O, or NULL on failure. Reseating the pointer by assigning a string literal merely updates the pointer variable without touching the buffer memory previously pointed to. As for memory changes you will need to use appropriate synchronization primitives after issuing DMA operations updating the buffer, or after any other form of asynchronously writes. These are low-level operations with many subtle pitfalls. Frankly I would recommend gaining more familiarity with the language first.

Comment: **As for memory changes you will need to use appropriate synchronization primitives after issuing DMA operations updating the buffer, or after any other form of asynchronously writes**. What do you mean by this? IOCtl calls?

Comment: And I understand memory management in C. I assumed the location of the mapped memory to the driver kernel memory would remap to the location of the literal when I changed it. It's more of a lack of familiarity with the GNU API. You are saying once you run that mmap command and point it to that buffer, it won't change unless explicitly demanded, meaning you must write characters directly to the memory locations of the buffer, being careful not to reassign the pointer.

Comment: In general the device which the DMA channel communicates with may read from or write to the buffer at any time, including while your application is half-way through accessing the buffer. Furthermore caches may hold stale or dirty data not yet written to memory. This requires synchronization to insure that neither side sees incorrect data. Alas will vary greatly though and you need to review the device implementation and system architecture manuals closely to determine the appropriate mechanism, some simple cases coherency protocols may even make this work transparently for you.

Comment: An architecture that might make more sense is to have the chip look at one dma buffer for input and let the output flow to another location that also has a dma buffer so the application can perform processing of the response. IE two DMA channels, one for read and one for write. That would avoid the concurrency issues you are mentioning, correct, assuming the GNU function gives some indication of when it is finished writing to the buffer?

Comment: `mmap` returns a pointer to a _specific_ memory block with particular properties. Changing `buf` changes what the pointer points to, setting the address to that of a string constant stored within your program instead while forgetting the original address given to you by `mmap`. This is the computer equivalent of typing in a new address for your friend in your address book and expecting the friend to move as a result.

Comment: Not exactly, it depends on the memory architecture and the protocol implemented by the device. Host-initiated DMA transfers and coherency requirements depend on the interface used, and in this case for a user-level interface will be mediated by a kernel driver and its guarantees. Of course of the device autonomously initiates operations then the synchronization mechanism will be inherently device-specific. It is difficult to make any general statements, direct memory accesses are non-portable mechanisms on which dirty tricks are sometimes played to increase performance.

Comment: do you have any documentation about what specifics will need to be addressed for a given device and what programming methods, especially related to Linux environment, there are for addressing them?